# Given an expression

Tags: calculus

How do I go from $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}}{b-a}$ to $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}}$. The question is how they are equal.

Comment: Hint: Conjugate

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

> $$\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}}{b-a}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$b-a=(\sqrt b)^2-(\sqrt a)^2=(\sqrt b-\sqrt a)(\sqrt b+\sqrt a),$$
we have
$$\frac{\sqrt b-\sqrt a}{b-a}=\frac{\sqrt b-\sqrt a}{(\sqrt b-\sqrt a)(\sqrt b+\sqrt a)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt b+\sqrt a}.$$

Comment: but how can you write $b-a$=........ is that a rule

Comment: @AlimTeacher: Since $b=(\sqrt b)^2,a=(\sqrt a)^2$, I used $B^2-A^2=(B-A)(B+A)$ for $B=\sqrt b,A=\sqrt a$.

Comment: Okay now I got it